# Keras / TensorFlow batches randomized?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For Keras as backend for TensorFlow with `model.fit(input, output,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,shuffle=True)` we can run the optimization by using mini batches (e.g. batch_size 32, 64, 128 and so forth).

As far as I understand from the documentation shuffle means that the dataset isn't shuffled after each epoch. So if I set shuffle=False. Does this mean that the dataset is not randomized and hence, the images are used in the same sequence as they are ordered in the input array and is this sequence kept for each epoch?

Comment: Yes.  If you use `model.fit`, `shuffle` shuffles the dataset prior to each epoch.  If you set it to false, that step will not occur and each epoch will train on the same sequence.  As a matter of personal taste that may actually help your efficiency, when working with categorical data, I prefer to use a data generator and then use `flow_from_directory` and `fit_generator` rather than `model.fit`.  This allows you to easily class your training images just by saving them to particular folders, while automatically randomizing and transforming them during batch creation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will consider using the fit_generator.